# Create a binary string of zeros, with variable length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the most elegant way to create a string of binary zeros, of type `varbinary(max)`, if the length is specified at run time (e.g., in a stored procedure)?

I could do it using the `REPLICATE` function, but this involves a lot of casting:

```
CAST(REPLICATE(CAST(CAST(0 AS tinyint) AS varbinary(max)), @size)
    AS varbinary(max))
```

(It doesn't even fit on the line...) Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**: The code should work for `@size > 8000`.

Comment: Maybe wrap your expression in a function to hide the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original form

```
CAST(REPLICATE(CAST(CAST(0 AS tinyint) AS varbinary(max)), @size)
    AS varbinary(max))
```

still suits my needs best.

Answer (score 0):

Better or just shorter?  :)

```
declare @size int
set @size = 3


select  CAST(REPLICATE(CAST(CAST(0 AS tinyint) AS varbinary(max)), @size) AS varbinary(max)),
        cast(replace(space(@size), ' ', 0x0) as varbinary(max))
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention a crucial requirement -- `SPACE` won't generate more than 8000 chars...

Answer (score 0):

```
; with Foo as (
  select 1 as Size
  union all
  select Size * 2
    from Foo
    where Size < 65536 )
  select Size, Cast( Replicate( Char( 0 ), Size ) as VarBinary(MAX) ) as WideZero
    from Foo
    option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```